# Why is std::array< T, 0 > not empty?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, stdarray

Given any `std::array< T, 0 >`, why is it not empty? I mean "empty" as in:

```
std::is_empty< std::array< int, 0 > >::value
```

... returning `false`, and

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <array>

struct Empty {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(std::tuple<int>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(std::tuple<int,Empty>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(std::tuple<int,std::array<int,0>>) << std::endl;
}
```

yields

```
4
4
8
```

This means that for `std::array<int,0>`, the empty base optimization (EBO) is not applied.

This seem especially strange to me given that `std::tuple<>` (note: no template parameters) *is* empty, i.e., `std::is_empty<std::tuple<>>::value` does yield `true`.

**Question:** Why is that, given that size `0` is already a special case for `std::array`? Is it intentional or an oversight in the standard?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The standard doesn't say anything about whether `tuple` or `array` should be empty, what you're seeing are implementation details, but there's no reason to make `tuple<>` non-empty, whereas there is a good reason for `array<T, 0>` being non-empty, consider:

```
std::array<int, sizeof...(values)> = { { values... } };
```

When the parameter pack is empty you'd get:

```
std::array<int, 0> = { { } };
```

For the initializer to be valid the object needs a member, which cannot be `int[0]` because you can't have zero-sized arrays as members, so a possible implementation is `int[1]`

An implementation doesn't have to special case the whole array, it can just do:

```
T m_data[N == 0 ? 1 : N];
```

and all other members work exactly the same way (assuming `end()` is defined as `begin()+N`)

Comment: GCC 4.8 seems to do it differently (or the libstdc++ coming with it), since `sizeof(std::array<int,0>) == 1`. But I realize you said "one *possible* implementation" and I accept the reasoning, so thanks!

Comment: GCC does `value_type _M_instance[_Nm ? _Nm : 1];` and I see `sizeof(array<int,0>) == sizeof(int)`

Comment: I see `sizeof(std::array<int,0>) == 1` for GCC 4.8 on LiveWorkSpace.org. Strange.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot it changed for GCC 4.8 to allow zero-sized arrays of non-DefaultConstructible types, see http://gcc.gnu.org/PR53248 (when gcc.gnu.org is back online). It now has an empty struct member instead of `value_type[1]`.

Comment: I just found §23.3.2.1/2 from the standard. Doesn't that mean that it's not just an implementation detail and that the standard *does* say something about `std::array<T,0>`'s emptiness (although indirectly)? As a consequence, if I read it correctly, an empty implementation would even be illegal, wouldn't it?

Comment: That's the clause I had in mind when I wrote my answer. I'm not 100% sure it requires non-empty, but I don't know any other way to make `{ { } }` work for an aggregate.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Wouldn't deriving from `class empty_t {};` work?

Comment: @Deduplicator in C++11 aggregates can't have base classes

Comment: Hm, that was introduced later? Ok.

Comment: N3337 [\[array\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/array#overview-2) doesn't seem to require nested braces to work properly.

Comment: @L.F. that wording was defective and changed, see https://wg21.link/lwg2590 and https://wg21.link/lwg2157 is also relevant.

Comment: OK.  However, doesn't "list-initialized with up to N elements" just mean `std::array<T, N> arr{a, b, c};`?  What am I missing?

Comment: @L.F. the double braces have to work, because there no other way to implement std::array. Did you look at 2157, which tries to address the zero-sized case explicitly, and makes it valid?

Comment: Well, per the resolution of 2157, `{{}}` is indeed allowed.  It is shown as Open though.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I said it _tries_ to address it. I'm just pointing out that it's a known problem and is being addressed.