# Are ={} and {}-style initializations the same in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, uniform-initialization, list-initialization

C++11 introduced {}-style initializations. But are these two forms

```
T x {...};
T x = {...};
```

the same?

Comment: As far as I know, yes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are not exactly the same. Maybe this can be illustrated by a counter-example:

```
struct Foo
{
  explicit Foo(std::initializer_list<int>) {}
};

int main()
{
  Foo f0{1, 2, 3};    // OK
  Foo f1 = {1, 2, 3}; // ERROR
}
```

So, the second variant requires that the type be implicitly constructable from an initialization list, whereas the first version doesn't. Note that the same applies for constructors of the form `Foo(int, int, int)`. I chose the `initializer_list<int>` as an example arbitrarily.

This would affect certain types written following the "explicit everywhere" philosophy (whereby people marked multi-parameter constructors `explicit` in C++03 code, even if it made no sense in that standard.)

Comment: A question: I have not understood why can you simply say `std::array<T,0> a = {};` (not an error but may give a warning) whereas `std::array<T,0> a{{}};` is necessary. Is there another difference for aggregate types?

Comment: @iavr I am not sure I follow. Both `std::array<T,0> a = {};` and `std::array<T,0> a{};` should be OK. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The example should be `std::array<int,2> a = {1, 2};` vs `std::array<int,2> b{{1, 2}};`. In the latter double braces are needed.

Comment: @iavr This really depends on your compiler. I get warnings in both cases with clang 3.4, and no warnings with gcc 4.8.2. Personally I think the requirement for extra braces is not required by the standard, but it is quite ambiguous about this. I think this is being fixed for C++14. (which may be why newer versions of gcc don't emit warnings: I am pretty sure older versions used to.)

Comment: Thanks, so if eventually `std::array<int,2> b{1, 2};` is valid and works on all compilers, then there will be no reason for `std::array<T,0>` to be non-empty, right? See [Why is std::array< T, 0 > not empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512827/why-is-stdarray-t-0-not-empty)

Comment: @iavr I don't know if that is also being addressed. It seems inconsistent to have a size-zero `std::array` be non-empty. But unless the future standard says something about it explicitly, anything goes.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the difference explained in juanchopanza's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22427384/241631), there is another difference, a breaking change, between *direct-list-initialization* and *copy-list-initialization* when it comes to `auto` and type deduction of the *braced-init-list*. Although it was [not added as part of C++14](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3912.html) (last Q&A item), the issue has been identified and it is up to the committee when it will be implemented.

For instance,

```
auto foo = {42};  // deduces foo as an initializer_list<int>
auto foo{42};     // deduces foo as an int
```

So direct-list-initialization never deduces an `initializer_list` from the argument. Consequently, the following will be ill-formed.

```
auto foo{1,2};    // cannot have multiple initializers for 
                  // direct-list-initialization when deducing type
```

But this is OK:

```
auto foo = {1,2}; // copy-list-initialization still deduces initializer_list<int>
```

The same applies to generalized captures within lambda expressions. Quoting [N3912](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3912.html)

```
[x{5}](){};        // x is int
[x{1,2}](){};      // ill-formed, no multiple initializers with direct-init
[x = {5}](){};     // ok, x is an initializer_list<int> with one element
[x = {1,2}](){};   // ok, x is an initializer_list<int> with two elements
```

Comment: This was not voted in for C++14.  See the last Q&A pair at the very end of the paper.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Thanks, I assumed it had been when it showed up with the other papers for C++14. Fixing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The *syntax* when using them in one case means different things

```
struct A { };

namespace X {
  struct A final {};
  struct A final = {};
}
```

In the first case, we are defining a struct called `A`, and in the second case we are defining an object called `final`.