# std::array member functions empty(), max_size() - useless but for consistency?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray

Are these member functions as useless as they seem and exist just to provide consistency with other containers?

For example:

```
std::array<int, 4> array1;  // size of 4 (but no elements initialized)
std::array<int, 0> array2;  // size of zero.

array1.empty();  // false - not empty even though no elements are initialized
array2.empty();  // true - empty and no way to add elements

array1.size();      // room for four now
array1.max_size();  // room for four forever

array2.size();      // no room for anything now
array2.max_size();  // ... or ever
```

The answer to "*[Why is std::array< T, 0 > not empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512827/why-is-stdarray-t-0-not-empty)*" deals with a zero "size" param and a non-zero return from `sizeof()`, i.e., it does take up space even when empty.  But that is not what I am asking.

Comment: All elements of a `std::array` are default initialised, if no explicit initialiser given.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are only there for consistency, allowing easier template specialisation.
Still your comment about `std::array<int, 4>` starting with no elements is wrong: It's a dressed up `int[4]`, now and forever.
To your aside, per standard no most-derived C++ object is ever smaller than 1.

Comment: To be clear, and for other readers, by "aside" you mean that other question I refer to?

Comment: yes, just added the info you alluded to with your link, even though it is not important to your question.

Answer (score 4):

You are wrong about a couple of things:

```
std::array<int, 4> array1;  // size of 4 but no elements
```

Not true. This array has 4 elements. It can only have 4.

```
array1.empty();  // false - no elements, but not empty
```

No, the array has 4 elements (it can only have 4). So it is not empty.

`std::arrays` are fixed size, and their size is determined by their type, not by whether any value has been assigned to their elements.

But you are right about the consistency argument: containers are required to have `size()` and `empty()` methods. For `std::array` not to have them would have required special rules. Having these methods makes is easier to use `std::array` in generic code.

Comment: OK - I corrected the corresponding comments in the sample code.